# Parametrizing SetUp for some tests, but not for others in Nunit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, fixtures

Suppose I have classes `A` and `B` in my System Under Test:

```
namespace SystemUnderTest;
public class A
{
   private int m_x;
   public int X => m_x;

   public A(int x)
   {
      m_x = x;
   }
}

public class B
{
   private A m_a;

   public A? AProperty => m_a;

   public int Y => m_a.X + 1;

   public B(A a)
   {
      m_a = a;
   }
}
```

Suppose I have the following tests:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using SystemUnderTest;

namespace Test
{
   [TestFixture]
   public class UnitTest1
   {
      private A m_a;
      private B m_b;

      [SetUp]
      public void Setup()
      {
         m_a = new A(1);
         m_b = new B(m_a);
      }

      [Test]
      public void Test1()
      {
         Assert.True(m_b.AProperty != null && m_b.AProperty.X == 1);
      }

      [Test]
      public void Test2()
      {
         Assert.True(m_b.Y == 2);
      }
   }
}
```

Suppose I would *only* like to parametrize the test for `A`'s property `X`. Suppose I do not want to parametrize anything else.

One way would be to get rid of the `SetUp` method altogether and introduce `TestCase` attributes:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using SystemUnderTest;

namespace Test
{
   [TestFixture]
   public class UnitTest2
   {

      [TestCase(0)]
      [TestCase(1)]
      public void Test1(int x)
      {
         A a = new A (x);
         B b = new B(a);
         Assert.True(b.AProperty != null && b.AProperty.X == x);
      }

      [Test]
      public void Test2()
      {
         A a = new A(1);
         B b = new B(a);
         Assert.True(b.Y == 2);
      }
   }
}
```

But this does involve repeating very similar code multiple times, since the second test depends on `A` to work, but doesn't really test any of the functionality in `A`.

Another way would be to parametrize the `TestFixture` as follows:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using SystemUnderTest;

namespace Test
{
   [TestFixture(0)]
   [TestFixture(1)]
   public class UnitTest3
   {
      private A m_a;
      private B m_b;
      private int m_x;

      public UnitTest3(int x)
      {
         m_x = x;
         m_a = new A(x);
         m_b = new B(m_a);
      }

      [Test]
      public void Test1()
      {
         Assert.True(m_b.AProperty != null && m_b.AProperty.X == m_x);
      }

      [Test]
      public void Test2()
      {
         m_a = new A(1);
         m_b = new B(m_a);
         Assert.True(m_b.Y == 2);
      }
   }
}
```

But now `Test2` runs twice, and I need to override the definitions of `m_a` and `m_b` each run.

So what I really need is to keep the `SetUp` method, and keep `A` inside of it, but then somehow to control what gets passed into the constructor of `A`.

Is there any out of the box solution for this in `Nunit`?

Answer (score 0):

`[Values]` Attribute might help you. Something like

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup([Values(0, 1)] int x)
{
   m_a = new A(x);
   m_b = new B(m_a);
}
```